# How to save dynamically created table row data to database

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my HTML and javascript script

```
<form method="POST" action="backend/backup.php">
  <div class="box-body col-sm-12">
    <input type="hidden" name="txtSlNo" id="txtSlNo" value="1">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label for="Date" class="control-label">Date:</label>
      <input type="text" class="text-right" name="date" id="date" value="<?php  echo date(" Y/M/D ")?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Amount:</label>
      <input type="text" size="7" class="text-right" name="txtAmount" id="txtAmount" oninput="calculate()" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Unit:</label>
      <input type="text" size="7" name="txtUnit" class="text-right" id="txtUnit" oninput="calculate()" value="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Total:</label>
      <input type="text" size="7" name="txtTotal" class="text-right" id="txtTotal" oninput="calculate();" oninput="addTotal();" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <br>
      <!--  <button name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary" hidden="hidden">Add</button>  -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="button" value="add" name="tableAdd" id="tableAdd" class="btn btn-primary add add1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <table id="tabledata" name="tabledata">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center !important;" id="select">select</th>
          <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center !important;">Sl.No</th>
          <th style="width: 125px; text-align: center !important;">Date</th>
          <th style="width: 175px; text-align: center !important;">Service</th>
          <th style="width: 80px; text-align: center !important;">Charge</th>
          <th style="width: 80px;">Amount</th>
          <th style="width: 80px;">Unit</th>
          <th style="width: 80px;">Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="delete-row" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
  <button class="print" onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>
  <br>
  <label class="GrandTotalLabel" id="GrandTotalLabel">GRAND TOTAL</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtGrandTotal" value="00.00" class="txtGrandTotal" oninput="addTotal();" id="txtGrandTotal" readonly/>
```

This is my javascript code

```
<div id="ta">

<script type="text/javascript">
var lclCount=0;
$("#tableAdd").click(function(){

       var sl_no = ($('#tabledata tr').length) - 1;

        lclCount++;
        sl_no++;

        var date = $("#date").val();
        var amount = $("#txtAmount").val();
        var unit = $("#txtUnit").val();
        var total = $("#txtTotal").val();
        var markup = "<tr><td class='mar'><input type='checkbox' class='chk' 
  name='record' id='"+ lclCount +"'></td><td name='slno' class='slno' id 
   ='slno-"+sl_no+"'>" 
         + sl_no + "</td><td class='date1' name='date'>"
         + date + "</td><td name='amount'>"
         + amount + "</td><td name='unit'>"
         + unit + "</td><td name='total' id='txtTot-"+lclCount+"'>"
         + parseFloat(total).toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>";
        $("#tabledata").append(markup);
        addTotal();

        refreshAdd();



    });
  </script>
  <!-- <div class="page-break"></div> -->
</div>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
```

and last here is my php code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "1234";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tad";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{
  $date = $_POST["date"];
  $amount = $_POST["txtAmount"];
  $unit = $_POST["txtUnit"];
  $total = $_POST["txtTotal"];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO backup_master (backup_date, backup_amount, backup_unit, backup_total) VALUES ('$date', '$amount', '$unit', '$total')";
  $result  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

Here I want to save the that generate from dynamically created table data to the database but I am tried a lot but not able to save to the database getting an error like undefined index date amount etc. here I want generate id for every row that for automatically generated table row but not getting how to generate is there any other solution foe this guys. Thank in Advance.

Comment: you forgot your php code

Comment: PHP code not displayed because of indent(space)  problem.

Comment: First: If your table has an ID column that has the auto_increment flag set, then there is no need for you to generate the value - the DB will do this for you.  Second:  It is usually a good practice to check that indexed columns have a value (as they usually can not be NULL/empty) before attempting to perform an INSERT.  IOWs, are you certain that backup_date had a value, and that it was a 'date' value?

Comment: I am not using sl_no and here I want to save this automatically generated data to database throwing an error as undefined index

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it, by using "arrays" on the inputs name, by defining the inputs name like arrays eg: "date" will be "date[]"

```
<form method="POST" action="backend/backup.php">
    <div class="box-body col-sm-12">
        <input type="hidden" name="txtSlNo" id="txtSlNo" value="1">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="Date" class="control-label">Date:</label>
            <input type="text" class="text-right" name="date[]" id="date" value="<?php  echo date(" Y/M/D ")?>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Amount:</label>
            <input type="text" size="7" class="text-right" name="txtAmount[]" id="txtAmount" oninput="calculate()" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Unit:</label>
            <input type="text" size="7" name="txtUnit[]" class="text-right" id="txtUnit" oninput="calculate()" value="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Total:</label>
            <input type="text" size="7" name="txtTotal[]" class="text-right" id="txtTotal" oninput="calculate();" oninput="addTotal();" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <br>
            <!--  <button name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary" hidden="hidden">Add</button>  -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="button" value="add" name="tableAdd" id="tableAdd" class="btn btn-primary add add1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table id="tabledata" name="tabledata">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center !important;" id="select">select</th>
                    <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center !important;">Sl.No</th>
                    <th style="width: 125px; text-align: center !important;">Date</th>
                    <th style="width: 175px; text-align: center !important;">Service</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px; text-align: center !important;">Charge</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px;">Amount</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px;">Unit</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px;">Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="delete-row" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
    <button class="print" onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>
    <br>
    <label class="GrandTotalLabel" id="GrandTotalLabel">GRAND TOTAL</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtGrandTotal" value="00.00" class="txtGrandTotal" oninput="addTotal();" id="txtGrandTotal" readonly/>
```

And on the server side, you iterate on the received arrays:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "1234";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tad";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{
    $numberOfRows = count($_POST['date']); // get the number of rows

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfRows; $i++) {
        $date = $_POST["date"][$i];
        $amount = $_POST["txtAmount"][$i];
        $unit = $_POST["txtUnit"][$i];
        $total = $_POST["txtTotal"][$i];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO backup_master (backup_date, backup_amount, backup_unit, backup_total) VALUES ('$date', '$amount', '$unit', '$total')";
        $result  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: still values are not inserting.

Comment: If the values are in the textbox that time correct values are inserting into the database but I add then not inserting. any solution

Comment: if I echo numberOfRows then getting 1 every time if there are 1 or more number of rows.

Comment: Where are you defining `$_POST["save"]` the save parameter. What's the output of `print_r($_POST) ` outside the if condition?

Comment: Array ( [txtSlNo] => 1 [date] => Array ( [0] => 2017/Nov/Sun ) [txtService] => Array ( [0] => ) [txtCharge] => Array ( [0] => ) [txtAmount] => Array ( [0] => ) [txtUnit] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [txtTotal] => Array ( [0] => ) [txtGrandTotal] => 24.00 [save] => save )

Comment: above is print_r($_POST) result.

Comment: Bro, will you answer for this.

Comment: how is your progress on this? When you made that print_r, was with only 1 row?

Comment: bro Are you there?